# How to render invalid HTML tags as text alongside valid HTML tags?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an HTML string in my code behind which has some valid html tags such as `<br/>`, `<p></p>`, and some invalid tags such as `<test>`. I want to render both sets of tags in  the browser in such a way that invalid tags are rendered as plain text.

For example, the string

`<test><br/>hi mark.<br/>how are you.My email is <test@test.com>`

would to need to output on the browser as

`<test>`
  hi mark.how are you.My email is `<test@test.com>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to whitelist the elements you consider to be valid, and then encode those which do not match the whitelist so that they are instead converted to `&lt;test&gt;` as opposed to `<test>`. The ampersand values will render as `<` text on the page.